# Can a simultaneously connect via ssh to a linux server running two network adapters each on a different vLAN?

Tags: ssh, networking, routing, systemd-networkd

I'm not new to linux but I'm not well versed in networking.

I have one single host (server) which uses systemd-networkd to assign interface names and static IP addresses.

Attached to the VM are two separate virtualized Networking Cards - which represent to different VLANS.  One networking card is within 10.0.40.0/255 and the other within 10.0.1.0/255.

I can initially assign each networking card a static address via systemd network files:

Network card eth0

```
[Match]
MACAddress=02:c0:1f:2b:12:8d

[Network]
Address=10.0.40.115/24
DNS=10.0.40.1

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=1025
```

Network card eth1

```
Match]
MACAddress=ee:95:e5:28:21:4c

[Network]
Address=10.0.1.117/24
DNS=10.0.1.1

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=10.0.1.1
Metric=1024
```

The routing table looks like this:

```
ip route show
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 1024
default dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 1025
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.117
10.0.40.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.40.115
```

Initially when rebooting I can access the computer via ssh at 10.0.40.115 and 10.0.1.117, however after about 30 seconds the 10.0.40.115 connection I receive  `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

I'm likely doing something I shouldn't be doing however I'm just wondering if this setup is even possible.  I'm assuming packets get sent from the ssh host back to the client get lost since they don't know what interface to pass back out of.

Thanks for any insight on the issue.

Comment: Using two default routes (and one immediately visible as bogus) is the cause. But if you want the details, you'll have to provide more details too: what is the client: a 3rd VM, the host, a remote system with the host doing DNAT? What is its IP address and on which side is it (eth0, eth1, eth1 beyond the gateway? Also, what is 10.0.1.1? a 4th VM, the host? etc.

Comment: The client is macBook with single IP address of 10.0.1.84 (en0 interface).  pfSense (10.0.1.1/10.0.40.1) router with networks 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.40.0/24.  Server is xcp-ng (10.0.40.12) hypervisor running virtualized Arch Linux (IPs 10.0.1.117 (en1) and 10.0.40.115 (en2)) installation. The actual hypervisor is connected through a single cable attached to eth3.  VIFs are created are the hypervisor attached to eth3 which hold the VLAN tags.  For this example I have two VIFs - one untagged and the other tagged VLAN 40.  eth0 associated with VIF0 and eth1 associated with VIF1.

Comment: Looks your setup is way more complex than what you wrote in the question (where there's only a single system described instead of all the systems). You'd better [add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/724660/edit) a schematic in the question and all relevant information for all relevant systems. Anyway I won't be able myself to answer anytime soon.